# Why isn't the QLabel on the QDialog box not showing?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

The dialog_box is appearing but the contents aren't displaying?

```
dialog_box=QtGui.QDialog()
dialog_box.setWindowTitle("NcrypT")
icon=QtGui.QIcon(image)
dialog_box.setWindowIcon(icon)

grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
grid.setSpacing(10)

info = QtGui.QLabel("Sending Mail..", dialog_box) #NOT WORKING
#grid.addWidget(info, 1, 0)

#dialog_box.setLayout(grid)
dialog_box.setFixedSize(175,100)
dialog_box.show()
```

Comment: Please give a more exact description of the problem. What do you see exactly (add a screenshot maybe), what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

You create a `QDialog` and then show it. You create a `QLabel` and then do nothing with it. It's strange that you appear to have commented out the part of the code that would have done this. If you want it to appear inside your `QDialog`, you will need to create a layout, add your `QLabel` instance to it, then set it as the dialog's layout.

This can be achieved by uncommenting the code that you commented out for some reason.

Comment: Then please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code sample and any tracebacks or error messages. Also, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).